# Overlay Layout over Grid on Android

Tags: android, grid, overlay, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create the following Layout in an Android, but I am not really successful:

4 Views are ordered as a Grid, just like dividing the screen in the horizontal and vertical middle.
On top of these views, centered in the middle, is a 5th View, and overlapping them (partly).
I tried LinearLayout in combination with RelativeLayout but I do not seem to manage getting this right. Any tips on this?

Thank you all very much, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo code .

```
<Relative fill_parent >
  <Linear  fill_parent orientatin=vertical>
    <Linear orientatin=horizontal layout_weight=1 >
       <Child1 layout_weight=1 />
        <Child2 layout_weight=1 />
    <Linear>
    <Linear orientatin=horizontal layout_weight=1 >
       <Child1 layout_weight=1 />
        <Child2 layout_weight=1 />
    <Linear>
  </Linear>

  <Linear centerInParent=true />
</relative>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. But it gives me the warning, that nested weights are bad for performance. Any Chance to prevent that?

Comment: yes you can avoid that by giving dp dimensions to parent linar layouts . like 240dp each . due to heavy measurement calculation nested wight is bad for performance . so its a tradeoff b/w performance and accuracy . by accuracy i mean dimension exactly same to the screen size . in dp approach this might not be the case for non standard device size . so i will vote for live with this warning .

Comment: I actually solved the nesting problem by using a centered strut in between, and then aligning the first level above/below that. Thanks!